# How to read specific attributes of xml in R

Tags: r, xml

Below is the sample XML file that I need to parse. This is only a part of the file original file is very large. But the format is always same.

I want to only parse these values and put it in a dataframe.

```
<Property Name="Entity1ID" Type="Edm.String">
      <Annotation Term="test.Label">
             <String>IDENTIFIER</String>
      </Annotation>
</Property>
```

So in dataframe I should have all the values like this

```
Entity1ID -> IDENTIFIER
ID -> FILEID
Entity2ID -> ID
```

And So on...

There is around 10 EntityType and 1000 property tag and I need to parse only property tag and map the values.

I am not able to parse the values.

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
    <edmx:Data>
        <Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="test.Models" Alias="test">
            <EntityType Name="Entity1">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="ID"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="Entity1ID" Type="Edm.String">
                    <Annotation Term="test.Label">
                        <String>IDENTIFIER</String>
                    </Annotation>
                </Property>
                <Property Name="ID" Type="Edm.String">
                    <Annotation Term="test.Label">
                        <String>FILEID</String>
                    </Annotation>
                </Property>
                <NavigationProperty Name="Subjects" Type="Collection(test.Subjects)"/>
                
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="Entity2">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="Entity2ID"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="Entity2ID" Type="Edm.String">
                    <Annotation Term="test.Label">
                        <String>ID</String>
                    </Annotation>
                </Property>
            </EntityType>
            <Function Name="GetData" EntitySetPath="asphalt/Entity2" IsBound="true">
                <Parameter Name="asphalt" Type="test.asphalt" Nullable="false"/>
                <Parameter Name="ID" Type="Edm.String"/>
                <ReturnType Type="Collection(test.Entity2)" Nullable="false"/>
            </Function>
            
            <Term Name="Label" Type="Edm.String"/>
            <EntityContainer Name="API">
                <EntitySet Name="Studies" EntityType="test.Entity1"/>
            </EntityContainer>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:Data>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Comment: what did you try that didn't work?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)

#test.xml is the file having XML data
xml_doc <- read_xml("test.xml")

Value <- xml_doc %>% 
  xml_find_all("//edmx:Data/d1:Schema/d1:EntityType/d1:Property/d1:Annotation/d1:String", ns=xml_ns(xml_doc)) %>% 
  xml_text()
Key <- xml_doc %>% 
  xml_find_all("//edmx:Data/d1:Schema/d1:EntityType/d1:Property", ns=xml_ns(xml_doc)) %>% 
  xml_attr("Name")

df <- data.frame(Key, Value)
df
```

Output is

```
        Key      Value
1 Entity1ID IDENTIFIER
2        ID     FILEID
3 Entity2ID         ID
```